# Where are my apps?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, restore

My handset was replaced under warranty and I was expecting my apps to sync to the new handset but when I check my apps in market none of them are listed.  Do I really have to manually find every single app and widget to download it separately?  Previously, such as after a factory reset, the apps would be listed and I could easily install them in one hit.  I am using the same Google account on the same type of Sony Ericcson Xperia Arc handset, albeit a new one.

Comment: You could try going to `Settings -> Privacy` and ensuring **Automatic restore** is checked, though I don't know if it will help.  Google has only ever remembered my paid apps when I've done a reset, so I always do a backup.

Comment: The [web based market](https://market.android.com/account) seems to remember installation history longer than the phone version.

Answer (score 5):

If you go into the web version of the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and then click on the link My Market Account at the top of the screen it shows you all the free and paid apps that you have downloaded since you opened your Android Google Account. From here you can also click the app name and then click the download button which then sends the download to your phone.

I've done this quite a few times when I have had to reinstall my phone

Hope this helps